# Validate only one spring annotation on form field and independently from others field

Tags: java, forms, spring, annotations, validation

i have a specific requirement even if it seems to be pretty straightforward.

I have a form for a user (give you a simplify version of it).

```
public class Form{
  @NotEmpty(message = "{empty}")
  @Size(min = 3, max = 32, message = "{size}")
  private String firstName;
  @NotEmpty(message = "{empty}")
  @Size(min = 3, max = 32, message = "{size}")
  private String lastName;
}
```

I want both field to be validate independently, fail at first error (only display one error message then).

For exemple, if i send firstName="" and lastName="aa", i want to get empty message for firstName and size message for lastName.

But by doing that i get 2 error messages for firstName (size and empty).

First alternative i found is using a @groupsequences but still cannot validate field independently.

So i created a new annotation :

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NotEmpty(message = "{empty}", groups = Check.firstTry.class)
@Size(min = 5, max = 32, message = "{size}", groups = Check.secondTry.class)
@GroupSequence({ Check.firstTry.class, Check.secondTry.class, Name.class })
public @interface Name {
    public abstract String message() default "{empty}";

    public abstract Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public abstract Class<?>[] payload() default {};
}
```

But it still validating every messages.

If i use @ReportAsSingleViolation it will always return the default message.

Did i miss something somewhere, form validation should be pretty easy for this case, it's not a weird case, is it ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom ConstraintValidator that checks the constraints one-by-one and reports the first one it finds. The (rather large) downside of this is that you end up reimplementing the checking mechanism for each component annotation, but you do get total control over the error messages.

```
public class MyConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Name, String> {

    private Name annotation;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyConstraintAnnotation annotation) {
        this.annotation = annotation;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String name, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (name == null) {
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(emptyMessage).addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        } else if (name.length() < getMinSize(annotation)) {
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(tooShortMessage).addConstraintViolation();    
            return false;
        } else if (name.length > getMaxSize(annotation)) {
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(tooLongMessage).addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe if you could get a handle on the ConstraintValidatorFactory and get the ConstraintValidators you need for each composing annotation? Although that exposes you to the internals of the implementation. It's not a perfect answer at all, but it would get what you need.

Comment: But it will always return the same error message.I want a different message for every constraint.

Comment: That's a way your right, thank you.But so it means i wasn't wrong their is no standard way for that?Am i the only one thinking that it should the basic configuration ?

Comment: For one thing, I don't know if java gives any guarantees that Annotations exist in any 'order', they are either there or not there. If that is the case then the concept of the 'first' constraint doesn't make much sense.

Comment: In fact, looking at the source for Class.java, annotations are held in a HashMap, so there is no order. Of course this is entirely implementation-dependent.

Comment: I still need to add a message in my annotation declaration, that always appear.can set it to a empty string but it means i always have two errors entries, one is the real one the other one is an empty String...Any solution for that ?

Comment: Found it, can set disableDefaultConstraintViolation